# open source Javascript library to create flow chart?

Tags: open-source, javascript, graphs, diagram, flowchart

I am looking for open source javascript library to create flow chart something like this
[image]

I have looked @ [Javascript framework to create flow-like diagrams](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/javascript-framework-to-create-flow-like-diagrams) and gojs is not open source.

Could you please point out library which can do like above diagram -- creating flow graph chart using drag and drop of components?

Thanks.

Comment: Best list is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript despite being on the wrong site...

Answer (score 0):

What about FlowChart-Vue?

- [Demo](https://joyceworks.github.io/flowchart-vue/) - interactive
- [github](https://github.com/joyceworks/flowchart-vue#readme) - code
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flowchart-vue) - for Installation

Or [D2Lang](https://d2lang.com/tour/hello-world) -  a diagram scripting language that turns text to diagrams.